# How do you simulate a supercapacitor in PLECS? or in MATLAB for that matter

Tags: supercapacitor, modeling

I've had a little bit of difficulty simulating a supercapacitor in both MATLAB and PLECS. Any ideas on how to do either?

Comment: Do you have a schematic? with two C's and 3R'S including leakage and dielectric absorption?, similar to any battery.

Comment: What about a supercap are you trying to simulate?

Answer (score 1):

Any capacitor has series inductance and resistance, these can be found in most capacitor datasheets. If your modeling it mathematically or graphically make sure you model the parasitics.

There is also [a paper (Modeling, Evaluation and Simulation of a
Supercapacitor Module for Energy Storage
Application)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiM2K273ZbTAhUH-GMKHR2zDlwQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atlantis-press.com%2Fphp%2Fdownload_paper.php%3Fid%3D22669&usg=AFQjCNFuc8sSDbiDMM2xv5PMOpfS-Ht8-Q&sig2=U_PP2C27t955nPW8PZk78w&cad=rja) that goes into detail on other effects that are different effects can be modeled for supercapacitors (the modeled capacitance can be dependent on the charge discharge rate)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLCxou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think you could implement a capacitor (super capacitor) in matlab by using the typical charge/discharge equations for an ideal capacitor. That is:

For charging:

$$ v_c=V_o\big(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\big)$$

For discharging:

$$ v_c=V_oe^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$

That's a behavioral model you can code pretty easily in MATLAB. This is of course assuming you are charging/discharging through a resistor. Depending on whether current is flowing into the capacitor or out of it, you can use some if-statement to use the corresponding equation.

If you needed the current, you can also find the decaying exponential function for the capacitor current which is readily available on the web.

I don't know how complex is the circuit you are trying to simulate, but the behavioral model can give you current and voltage values at time 't' in the capacitor.

Comment: What about the parasitics? super caps are not ideal

Comment: @laptop2d that's why I said that I didn't know how complex he wanted that to be and put the ideal capacitor as a starting point. You can have it as complex as you need it. But the question wasn't that specific

Answer (score 0):

Simulink comes with a supercapacitor (admittedly you do need the simPowerSystem's module)

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/supercapacitor.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Mathwork have provided the block and equations so you could reproduce in just the s-domain or in PLECS
[image]